# How I can make sure my code is keep running?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, automation

hey I am running an optimization model in AMPL. It is huge model and I know it is gonna take a lot to be solved. How I can make sure my model keep running even when the screen become lucked? 
I did the following as well,

I installed coffeine and it is in enable mode.

I typed  caffeinate in terminal .

How I can make sure it is keeping running?

Comment: Are you open to dead simple old school hardware solutions? https://www.amazon.com/WiebeTech-Programmable-Mouse-Jiggler-MJ-3/dp/B00MTZY7Y4/

Comment: Is there anyway you can make your code write intermittent results to the screen or to a file. If so you could easily verify if your code runs continuously.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be install a GUI app. A good one is [KeepingYouAwake](https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake). This app is a GUI front-end to `caffeinate` command. It's very simple to install and configure, and keeps your computer from sleeping.

You can install it via Homebrew by running:

`brew cask install keepingyouawake`

If you don't have Homebrew installed, you can follow the instructions to install it on it's homepage:

https://brew.sh

Comment: I downloaded it from google, now the icon is in the top next to my coffeine! why you sent me that complicated link for installation?

Comment: also how I can know my code keep running? I had coffeine before! there are kind of the same

Comment: See https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/02/17/amphetamine-keepingyouawake-for-mac/ for the differences beween coffeine and keepingyouawake.  The complicated instructions are for those that have not installed Caffeine already.  As you point out both programs are similar front end programs for the same backend caffeine command.  As far as telling that it is running you'll have to create some kind of output in a gui or in the terminal like @bmike said.